# How can i flip my statement with my switch in c?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

right now my code writes out 37 as seven three. how can i switch it to say three seven? ive got all of the other things i need to make this work at the moment besides that switch. please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

        int x;

        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");

        do{

                switch (x%10)

        {
        case 0:
                printf("zero ");
                break;
        case 1:
                printf("one ");
                break;
        case 2:
                printf("two ");
                break;
        case 3:
                printf("three ");
                break;
        case 4:
                printf("four ");
                break;
        case 5:
                printf("five ");
                break;
        case 6:
                printf("six ");
                break;
        case 7:
                printf("seven ");
                break;
        case 8:
                printf("eight ");
                break;
        case 9:
                printf("nine ");
                break;
        };

        x=x/10;
        }while(x>0);

        printf("\n\n");



        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works.

To handle 37, you first get its number of digits which is 2. Then you can parse this integer from left to right.

Hope it is helpful to you!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {

int x;

printf("Please enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");

int len = 1;

for(len = 1; ; len = len * 10){

if(x / len == 0){
    break;
}

}

len = len / 10;


do{

      switch (x/len)

    {
    case 0:
          printf("zero ");
          break;
    case 1:
          printf("one ");
          break;
    case 2:
          printf("two ");
          break;
    case 3:
          printf("three ");
          break;
    case 4:
          printf("four ");
          break;
    case 5:
          printf("five ");
          break;
    case 6:
          printf("six ");
          break;
    case 7:
          printf("seven ");
          break;
    case 8:
          printf("eight ");
          break;
    case 9:
          printf("nine ");
          break;
    };

    x = x % len;
    len = len / 10;

}while(x>0);

printf("\n\n");



return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried your solutiion here but what i got if i typed in lets say 73 was three three. i'm guessing it reads two numbers but only writes the second one. whats a way to bypass that?

Comment: also in the for statement what goes in the second part. i got i=1; ;i=i*10

Comment: oh yes alright. i had a major missread that caused it. works like a charm now. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad my answer is helpful for you:)

Answer (score 3):

You can always write a recursive function to do your printing like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printnumber(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) return;
    printnumber(num / 10);

    switch (num % 10)
    {
        case 0; printf("zero "); break;
        case 1; printf("one "); break;
        case 2; printf("two "); break;
        case 3; printf("three "); break;
        case 4; printf("four "); break;
        case 5; printf("five "); break;
        case 6; printf("six "); break;
        case 7; printf("seven "); break;
        case 8; printf("eight "); break;
        case 9; printf("nine "); break;
    }

    // uncommment the below line and comment the 
    // printnumber() call above to print the number
    // backwards

    // printnumber(num / 10);
}

int main (void)
{
        int x;

        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");

    printnumber(x);

        printf("\n\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a c programmer, but if you can't traverse the number from right to left, then

```
switch (x - x%10 * 10)
```

and

```
x = floor(x/10);
```

EDIT: THE ABOVE GOES IN THE WRONG DIRECTION

```
switch (floor(x/10^floor(log10(x))))
```

And

```
x -= floor(x/10^floor(log10(x))) * 10^floor(log10(x))
```

That will take you left-to-right instead of right-to-left (adding some variables in might increase calculational efficiency, though.

Comment: Uh, you're wrong.  1234 - 1234%10 * 10 = 4 (the right-most digit).  floor(1234/10) = 123... it does what the poster asks and moves from right to left.

Comment: Oh, hell, it was supposed to go from left to right. doh!  I'll rework the math and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to reverse your number.
It's not static you can enter any number you want.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int getd(int n)
{
    return (int)log10(n);
}
int get(int n,int i,int digit)
{
    int p;
    p=(int)pow(10,i-1);
    n=n/p;
    return n%10;
}
int reverse(int n)
{
    int digit;
    digit=getd(n)+1;
    int a,i,j;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1,j=digit-1,sum=0 ; i<=digit ; i++,j-- )
    {
        a=get(n,i,digit);
        sum=sum+(a*(int)pow(10,j));
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<reverse(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any memory constraint? If no, consider a temporarily array to store each digits in the number. Then you can print it in any direction you want.

Pseudo code,

```
int arr[50];
int count = 0;
while (number != 0)
{
    arr[count++] = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
}
for (int i=count-1; i>=0; i--)
{
     // print arr[i] in word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if the integer math is a required part of the process, but if it isn't you can get what you want more easily by doing a character-based loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   char buf[64] = "";
   printf("Please enter an integer: ");
   (void) fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

   printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");
   const char * b = buf;
   while(*b)
   {
      switch(*b)
      {
         case '0':  printf("zero ");  break;
         case '1':  printf("one ");   break;
         case '2':  printf("two ");   break;
         case '3':  printf("three "); break;
         case '4':  printf("four ");  break;
         case '5':  printf("five ");  break;
         case '6':  printf("six ");   break;
         case '7':  printf("seven "); break;
         case '8':  printf("eight "); break;
         case '9':  printf("nine ");  break;
         default:   /* empty */       break;
      }
      b++;
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the number to the switch,reverse the number.